# persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK leading to lost RDDs however MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER working fine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am on spark 3.3.1 and my cluster configuration is as follows (it is only 1 executor with 3 cores and 4GB executor memory):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import storagelevel

spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",False).\
config("spark.executor.cores","3").\
config("spark.executor.instances","1").\
config("spark.executor.memory","4G").\
config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", True).\
getOrCreate()
```

I read in a CSV (linked at the end) whose details are:

- size on disk - 12.13 GB
- size in memory deserialized - 3.6 GB
- size in memory serialized - 1965.2 MB

When I try to persist the csv with `MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER` storage level (default for df.cache()), it works fine. however when I try to persist the csv with `MEMORY_AND_DISK` storage level, it results in various rdd losses (`WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_13_3 !`) and bad nodes (`YarnAllocator: Container from a bad node: ...`) and then eventually finishes the action but, the persisted data so far is lost when the bad node occured and all that eventually ends up persisting is only what was not persisted when the node went bad

Can you help me understand what is happening here? My block size is also only 128 MB so I cannot see what could be going wrong. Also, can you help me construct an example with a CSV with random data that I can dump on the disk and then later on read with your suggested cluster configuration and persist it with `DISK_AND_MEMORY` storage level such that it uses both the memory and the disk

I have used the data from [here](https://data.cdc.gov/Case-Surveillance/COVID-19-Case-Surveillance-Public-Use-Data-with-Ge/ynhu-f2s2) in case you want to try and see on your end.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How did you test both storage strategy? Are you testing in the same Spark application (persist using `MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER` first, then persist using `MEMORY_AND_DISK`), or using two separate Spark Application?

Comment: Separate applications. I'm starting the spark session afresh every time